# Spring MVC cannot convert from java.lang.String to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, arraylist, type-conversion, javabeans

I'm selecting values in check boxes and passing them over to the form backing bean. These values are `User` objects that are stored in an `ArrayList<User>` in a form backing bean.

However, when I submit the form I get the above error and then the log says something like "there is no converter that can handle this conversion".

First of all, why is it even storing the `User`objects as an array of Strings? `String[]`

Then it is trying to convert it to `ArrayList`but cannot find a converter?

I don't understand.

Comment: First you should add a stacktrace instead giving a half of error, add your views implementation because i guess that you bind users in wrong way to the form

Comment: Jackson dependencies are missing in the classpath maybe?